# Deriving $1-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k+1}}{3^k}\alpha=1-\alpha(1-(\frac{2}{3})^n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

> There is the following sum: $1-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k+1}}{3^k}\alpha=1-\alpha(1-(\frac{2}{3})^n)$ where $\alpha\in(0,1]$

I do not understand the following equality. I thought it could be derived using geometric series sum:

$1-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k+1}}{3^k}\alpha=1-2^{-1}\alpha\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k}}{3^k}=1-2^{-1}\alpha(\frac{1-(\frac{2}{3})^n}{\frac{1}{3}})=1-\frac{3}{2}\alpha(1-(\frac{2}{3})^n)$

**Question:**

Why is the equality ,I derived,  different from the initial one presented?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Winther The answer made me spot the mistake when copiying from the book. In the original rext it is written ($2^{k-1}$). It was not with the any intention of invalidating the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a typo in the question statement.

$$1-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k\color{red}-1}}{3^k}\alpha=1-2^{-1}\alpha\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k}}{3^k}=1-2^{-1}\left( \frac23\right)\alpha(\frac{1-(\frac{2}{3})^n}{\frac{1}{3}})=1-\alpha(1-(\frac{2}{3})^n)$$

and you forgot the first term in the geometric sum.

Comment: Yes you are right about the typo.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is in the statement
$$
    1 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^{k+1}}{3^k} = 1 - 2^{-1} \alpha \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^k}{3^k}.
$$
The correct expression is
$$
    1 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^{k+1}}{3^k} = 1 - 2 \alpha \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^k}{3^k},
$$
since $2 \times 2^k = 2^{k+1}$.

Comment: Typo was fixed. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the first term of a geometric series.

$$\frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{9}+\frac{8}{27}+…$$

$$u_1 = \frac{2}{3} \quad r = \frac{2}{3}$$

Hence,

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^k = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{2}{3}\cdot\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^{k-1} = \frac{\frac{2}{3}\big(1-\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^n\big)}{1-\frac{2}{3}} = 2\bigg(1-\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^n\bigg)$$

Your error was that you took $u_1 = 1$, leading to an incorrect result.